# What is .WithTransparentBounds?

Tags: regex, swift, foundation, nsregularexpression

I have a need to collapse multiple whitespace into one space. After digging around in Foundation Framework NSString Class Reference, Google, and stackoverflow, I found enough information and sample code to get me to

```
var myString = "Snoopy      Doogitz"

if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression( pattern: "\\s+", options: [] ) {
    let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString( myString, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange( 0, myString.characters.count ), withTemplate: " ")
    print( modString )
}
```

which works.

However, I can't seem to find an explanation in documentation for .WithTransparentBounds

If I remove it from my code

```
var myString = "Snoopy      Doogitz"

if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression( pattern: "\\s+", options: [] ) {
    let modString = regex.stringByReplacingMatchesInString( myString, options: [], range: NSMakeRange( 0, myString.characters.count ), withTemplate: " ")
    print( modString )
}
```

That works just fine, too. But before I leave this, I'd love to know what the option .WithTransparentBounds actually means, for someday I might need it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the comment in NSRegularExpression.h:

> `NSMatchingAnchored`, `NSMatchingWithTransparentBounds`, and `NSMatchingWithoutAnchoringBounds` can apply to any match or replace method.  If `NSMatchingAnchored` is specified, matches are limited to those at the start of the search range.  **If `NSMatchingWithTransparentBounds` is specified, matching may examine parts of the string beyond the bounds of the search range, for purposes such as word boundary detection, lookahead, etc.**  If `NSMatchingWithoutAnchoringBounds` is specified, `^` and `$` will not automatically match the beginning and end of the search range (but will still match the beginning and end of the entire string).  `NSMatchingWithTransparentBounds` and `NSMatchingWithoutAnchoringBounds` have no effect if the search range covers the entire string.

Here's an example that illustrates the difference when you include WithTransparentBounds:

```
let str = "foobarbaz"

let re = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "bar\\b", options: [])
re.numberOfMatchesInString(str, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: 9)) // returns 0
re.numberOfMatchesInString(str, options: .WithTransparentBounds, range: NSRange(location: 3, length: 3)) // returns 0
re.numberOfMatchesInString(str, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 3, length: 3)) // returns 1
```